# Highlight Search (hls) matches of multiple search terms with different colors

Tags: vim, search, colors, gvim

Many times when working on code, I search for the occurrences of variables with similar names. For examples, find all matches of `var1` and `var2` as:

```
/\<var1\>\|\<var2\>
```

Now I really like the Highlight Search feature of Vim, b/c once I do the search, all the matching instances pop out in yellow color.

Is there a way to assign different colors to different terms in the search string? That is, all matches of `var1` be yellow and of `var2` be green?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `'hlsearch'` option, no, they all have to appear in the same color.  However, you can use the `:match` feature instead.  For example:

```
:match TODO /var1/
:2match Type /var2/
:3match Comment /var3/
```

This, of course, is more cumbersome than straight `'hlsearch'` matching, because it requires you to know what syntax coloring groups are already defined, or define your own.  Also, you can only do up to three separate matches this way.  If you need more, you'll have to use `matchadd()` instead.

See:

```
:help :match
:help :highlight
:help highlight-groups
:help matchadd()
```

Comment: Very nice! However, the drawback (other than the obvious cumbersomeness) is that the match is local to the window (or buffer?) and does not effect adjacent windows (which is a very useful feature when working on a project with multiple source modules).

Comment: I forgot to mention that part of it, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in search cannot do that, but there are plugins that let you use different colors, for example my own [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666). (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.) Most of these use the `matchadd()` functionality, ensure that this is globally applied to all windows, and provide a search-like interface through mappings and commands.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll need to find some time to research this plugin!